# Clearest way to build html elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, element

I've seen a lot of different styles (and few different methods) of creating elements in jQuery. I was curious about the **clearest** way to build them, and also if any particular method is objectively better than another for any reason. Below are some *examples* of the styles and methods that I've seen.

```
var title = "Title";
var content = "Lorem ipsum";

// escaping endlines for a multi-line string
// (aligning the slashes is marginally prettier but can add a lot of whitespace)
var $element1 = $("\
    <div><h1>" + title + "</h1>\
        <div class='content'>  \
        " + content + "        \
        </div>                 \
    </div>                     \
");

// all in one
// obviously deficient
var $element2 = $("<div><h1>" + title + "</h1><div class='content'>" + content + "</div></div>");

// broken on concatenation
var $element3 = $("<div><h1>" +
                title + 
                "</h1><div class='content'>" +
                content +
                "</div></div>");

// constructed piecewise
// (I've seen this with nested function calls instead of temp variables)
var $element4 = $("<div></div>");
var $title = $("<h1></h1>").html(title);
var $content = $("<div class='content'></div>").html(content);
$element4.append($title, $content);

$("body").append($element1, $element2, $element3, $element4);
```

Please feel free to demonstrate any other methods/styles you might use.

Comment: In the three first examples, why do you use jquery ? Writing complete html in a jquery selector is just a loss of performance. `var element2 = "<div><h1>"+title+"</h1>...</div>";`

Comment: I'm manipulating these elements with jQuery as well, so if I didn't create them with jQuery I'd have to use a jQuery selector anyway.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Templates are great and if you have access to them in your project, I suggest you use them. If you're using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#template) it's built in. In some cases however, you will need to build HTML in your code whether it's refactoring or testing. I've found that the below format is the clearest to read when that is the requirement.

Note: The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) allows single OR double quotes for attributes in your markup so don't bother with all the crazy escaping.

```
this.$fixture = $([
  "<div>",
  "  <div class='js-alert-box'></div>",
  "  <form id='my-form-to-validate'>",
  "    <input id='login-username' name='login-username'>",
  "  </form>",
  "</div>"
].join("\n"));
```

Comment: Wow! Absolutely perfect. It took almost fully two years to get an answer to the actual question that is readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: I like this. What would you think of `.join("\n")` instead of `.join("")`?

Comment: Note that in typescript you can use template strings https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html

Comment: using "this.$fixture", beyond jQuery, do I need to install anything else?

Answer (score 54):

After looking around for a while, I found the style which I finally settled on. First, I'll say that I used Mustache for templating, and it worked well. Sometimes, though, you just need to build an element one time, without reusing it, or have some other motivation to not bring in another library. In this situation, I have taken to using:

```
$("body")
.append(
    $("<div>")
    .append(
        $("<div>")
        .append(
            $("<h1>").text(title)
        )
    )
    .append(
        $("<div>").text(content)
    )
);​
```

This works because `append()` returns a reference to the object you're *appending **to***, so chained `append()`s attach to the same object. With proper indentation, the structure of the markup is obvious, and this way it's easy to modify. Obviously this is slower than using templates (the whole thing has to be built piece by piece), but if you're only using it for initialization or something similar then it is a great compromise.

There are many ways one could format a construct like this, but I've chosen a way to make it clear what's going on. The rule I used is that there should be a maximum of one opening parenthesis and/or one closing parenthesis on each line. Also, the leaves of these append trees do not need to be passed to the jQuery constructor, but I've done so here for visual repetition.

Comment: By far the most cleanest jQuery-esque method than having it inside quotations as shown in the accepted answer. The accepted answer feels like having HTML code inside a PHP `echo` /shudder

Comment: `$("<h1>" + title + "</h1>")` could be `$("<h1>").text(title)`

Comment: Will all these `.append()` calls adversely affect performance compared to constructing a string (e.g. in a var) and appending it with one `.append()`?

Comment: It may be useful to remember that `.append()` can also accept an array. This may come in handy when trying to build lists, for example. Can then use an anonymous function self-calling function to generate the list of `<li>s`. [Something like `.append(  (function () { ... return li; })()  )`]

Comment: @adamj - I'm the opposite - I prefer the accepted version because it's easier to read due to actually resembling nested markup.

Answer (score 33):

When it comes to DOM building I try to avoid string concatenations as they might lead to subtle bugs and non properly encoded output.

I like this one:

```
$('<div/>', {
    html: $('<h1/>', {
        html: title
    }).after(
        $('<div/>', {
            'text': content,
            'class': 'content'
        })
    )
}).appendTo('body');
```

generates:

```
    ...
    <div><h1>some title</h1><div class="content">some content</div></div>
</body>
```

and it ensures proper HTML encoding and DOM tree building with matching opening and closing tags.

Comment: I was going to add an example for this, but I'd never seen it done readably. This method is pretty clear though.

Answer (score 22):

My advice : don't try to build html elements with jQuery, it's not its responsability.

Use a Javascript templating system like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [**HandlebarJs**](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

With a very limited number of line, you can create your html elements directly from a Javascript object. It's not complicated, only 2 functions and a template.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>

var context  = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"}
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template-skeleton"));
var html     = template(context);
```

**Edit:**
Another example without html, pure Javascript (from [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/)) :

```
var skeleton = '<div><h1>{{title}}</h1><div class="content">{{content}}</div></div>';
var data = { title: "Some title", content: "Some content" };
var html = Mustache.to_html(skeleton, data);
```

It is much more maintainable than a series of concatenation.

Comment: I hadn't looked into templating systems much. I like this syntax a lot. However, currently I'm working in an MVC framework, and my javascript is nicely separated from my actual view templates. This means my js templates would have to be constructed as strings (in their respective .js files) anyway, or else break the law of demeter by reaching for a js template defined in the html template. +1 regardless, because this would be a good solution in any other situation.

Comment: It seems not incompatible. See my second example.

Comment: After actually trying it, this turned out to be a really good solution. The syntax is obvious and because these templates are so small, they look nice when embedded right into the .js files. Plus I can still use the escaped line breaks if my templates get crazy.

Answer (score 15):

**2015 answer**:

For ES6, use [JavaScript template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
var str = `
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>❤ unicorns</h1>
    </body>
</html>`
```

For older browsers, use [multiline](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multiline).

```
var str = multiline(function(){/*
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>❤ unicorns</h1>
    </body>
</html>
*/});
```

Comment: This is so much simpler than using `.append`s all over the place.

Comment: It's nice to see the structure of the html and be able to pass in variables cleanly using the ${myVar} feature that template strings has. This way is kind of how React JSX looks, which everybody is using now.

Answer (score 8):

This is adapted from Baer's answer. I find it more readable, no need to create and join an array, no need to put quotes around every line:

http://jsfiddle.net/emza5Ljb/

```
var html =

    '                                                           \
      <div>                                                     \
        <div class="js-alert-box"></div>                        \
        <form id="my-form-to-validate">                         \
          <input id="login-username" name="login-username">     \
        </form>                                                 \
      </div>                                                    \
    '

// using jQuery:
//
var dom = $( html )

// or if you need performance, don't use jQuery
// for the parsing.
// http://jsperf.com/create-dom-innerhtml-vs-jquery
//
var div       = document.createElement( 'div' )
div.innerHTML = html
var dom = $( div )
```

FYI, when performance isn't an issue and elements contain a lot of dynamic data, I sometimes just write code like this (note that closure compiler will throw a warning about the unquoted class property, but in modern browsers this works fine):

```
$(
      '<a></a>'

    , {
           text     : this.fileName
         , href     : this.fileUrl
         , target   : '_blank'
         , class    : 'file-link'
         , appendTo : this.container
      }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that uses [$(htmlString)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) and mimics the standard layout of HTML code:

```
function getPage(title, contents) {
  return (
    $("<div>", {id: "container", class: "box"}).append(
      $("<div>", {class: "title"}).append(
        $("<h1>").text(title)
      ),
      $("<div>").html(contents)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This way is most flex if you need to attach a lot of event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly look into javascript view templates:

http://embeddedjs.com/

http://jupiterjs.com/news/jquery-view-client-side-templates-for-jquery

http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.View

Answer (score 2):

I find the functional approach very convenient. For instance

```
// reusable generics TABLE constructor helpers
var TD = function(content) { return $('<td>', { html: content }) }
var TH = function(content) { return $('<th>', { html: content }) }
var TR = function(cell, cells) {  // note the kind of cell is a 2^order parameter
    return $('<tr>', { html: $.map(cells, cell) })
}

// application example
THEAD = $('<thead>', {html:
    TR(TH, [1,2,3,4])})
TBODY = $('<tbody>', {html: [
    TR(TD, ['a','b','c','d']),
    TR(TD, ['a','b','c','d']),
]})
```

now the call

```
$('#table').append($('<table>', {html: [THEAD, TBODY]}))
```

yields

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

*edit*

I have refined my approach, now available for instance as [html_uty.js](https://github.com/CapelliC/jquery.cctt/blob/master/extra/html_uty.js)

Comment: You are using `html` as if it were an attribute, as in `{ html: content }`, but it seems to behave differently. Where is that [interesting feature documented](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)?

Comment: maybe after `As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property...` But I vaguely remeber I found it by trial-and-error, not from docs, while attempting to build my mini react-like scripts. BTW now I have refined the construct (specially the style attr cannot be handled directly, I'll add a link to github into the answer)

Comment: I really like this scripting without a template language. It's still bending my brain (as $.map always does, not to mention your passing an _array_ to $.html) but I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of doing this using backticks -

```
var optionsForLength =  `
    <option value="Kilometre">Kilometre</option>
    <option value="Metre">Metre</option>
    <option value="Centimetre">Centimetre</option>
    <option value="Milimetre">Milimetre</option>
    <option value="Micrometre">Micrometre</option>
    <option value="Nanometre">Nanometre</option>
    <option value="Mile">Mile</option>
    <option value="Yard">Yard</option>
    <option value="Foot">Foot</option>
    <option value="Inch">Inch</option>
`;
```

Or you can use single quotes as well to wrap your HTML inside javascript -

```
var optionsForLength = 
'<option value="Kilometre">Kilometre</option>'+
'<option value="Metre">Metre</option>'+
'<option value="Centimetre">Centimetre</option>'+
'<option value="Milimetre">Milimetre</option>'+
'<option value="Micrometre">Micrometre</option>'+
'<option value="Nanometre">Nanometre</option>'+
'<option value="Mile">Mile</option>'+
'<option value="Yard">Yard</option>'+
'<option value="Foot">Foot</option>'+
'<option value="Inch">Inch</option>'+
'<option value="Nautical mile">Nautical mile</option>';
```

Comment: Sometimes we tend to overwork things, and this approach is by far simplest. I take it a step further by copying the formatted HTML into Excel, then use simple formulas to wrap each line within quotes (including whitespaces), then copy the formula results into my JS file. This provides me with wonderfully formatted HTML (and even that is overkill!).