# how to create generic html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following html:

```
<div  id="prog" class="downloads clearfix">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image_container">
            <img src="/img/downloads/company.png" width="168" height="238" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            pricelist:  <label id="pr1"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="type">
            pdf document 
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a id="pdfdocument" class="button" target="_blank" href="#">start Download </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want build HTML which is inside the `<div id="prog">` with Javascript:

```
<div id="prog" class="downloads clearfix"></div>
```

I'm trying to use this Javascript, but without success:

```
var tmpDocument, tmpAnchorTagPdf, tmpAnchorTagXls, parentContainer, i;
parentContainer = document.getElementById('prog');

for (i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    tmpDocument = documents[i];
    tmpAnchorTagPdf = document.createElement('a id="pdfdocument" ');
    tmpAnchorTagPdf.href = '/role?element=' + contentElement.id + '&handle=' + ope.handle;
    tmpAnchorTagPdf.innerHTML = 'start Download';

    tmpAnchorTagXls = document.createElement('a');
    tmpAnchorTagXls.href = '/role?element=' + contentElement.id + '&handle=' + ope.handle;
    tmpAnchorTagXls.innerHTML =  'start Download';

    parentContainer.appendChild(tmpAnchorTagPdf);
    parentContainer.appendChild(tmpAnchorTagXls);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? If so, what are the errors? Are you getting output that doesn't match what you want? If so, what is the undesired output and how does it differ from the desired output?

Comment: Why not just take html as string and do $('#prog').html(varHTML);

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760328/clearest-way-to-build-html-elements-in-jquery

Comment: Are you **sure** the jQuery tag is correct? Your code doesn't mention jQuery anywhere.

Comment: For what it's worth, I added an answer below that uses a div template method. The HTML code above has about 11 different HTML elements that would all have to be created do this without a template of some kind. Not impossible of course... it just seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a section of code that you will be using more than once, you could take the following approach.

Here is the original `div` without the code you want to create:

```
<div id="prog" class="downloads clearfix">
</div>
```

Create a template in a hidden `div` like:

```
<div id="itemtemplate" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image_container">
            <img src="/img/downloads/company.png" width="168" height="238" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            pricelist:  <label></label>
        </div>
        <div class="type">
            pdf document 
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a class="button" target="_blank" href="#">start Download </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then duplicate it with jquery (OP originally had a jquery tag; see below for JS), update some HTML in the duplicated div, then add it to the document

```
function addItem() {
    var item = $("#itemtemplate div.item").clone();

    //then you can search inside the item
    //let's set the id of the "a" back to what it was in your example
    item.find("div.link a").attr("id", "pdfdocument");

    //...the id of the label
    item.find("div.title label").attr("id", "pr1");

    //then add the objects to the #prog div
    $("#prog").append(item);
}
```

**update**

Here is the same `addItem()` function for this example using pure Javascript:

```
function JSaddItem() {
    //get the template
    var template = document.getElementById("itemtemplate");

    //get the starting item
    var tempitem = template.firstChild;    

    while(tempitem != null && tempitem.nodeName != "DIV") {
        tempitem = tempitem.nextSibling;
    }
    if (tempitem == null) return;

    //clone the item
    var item = tempitem.cloneNode(true);

    //update the id of the link
    var a = item.querySelector(".link > a");
    a.id = "pdfdocument";

    //update the id of the label
    var l = item.querySelector(".title > label");
    l.id = "pr1";

    //get the prog div
    var prog = document.getElementById("prog");

    //append the new div
    prog.appendChild(item);
}
```

I put together a [JSFiddle with both approaches here](http://jsfiddle.net/LCFEr/1/).

Comment: Even better: use the template element http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

Comment: Besides the tag, the question likely is not about jQuery, seeing how the OP uses it nowhere (quite the oppsote, actually).

Comment: I like it (the `template` object). I was not aware of it. Though, I was thinking that in this case it might be nice that the image he has would possibly be loaded already and would not have to load when the `div` is added to the DOM. In reading about `template` images do not preload.

Comment: @Ingo Bürk: I noticed your comment above after my answer.. I'm currently working on a non-Jquery solution as well.

Comment: non-jquery: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/#toc-using

Comment: Answer updated. I did not use the `template` example that @Yoeri suggested. But it is definitely something I am going to have to explore.