# How can I format output in jquery to a div?

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a form maker that allows me to create a form but can't format the output in a similar fashion to pretty print.

Tried using \n and pre tags too

```
    allCont += "<label>"+insCleaned+"</label><input type='text' name='"+dval+insCleaned+"' /><p><?php echo "<?php if(isset(\$GLOBALS['postErrArray']['"?>"+ dval + insCleaned + "<?php echo "'])){echo \$GLOBALS['postErrArray']['"; ?>" + dval + insCleaned + "<?php echo "'];} ?>";?></p><br>";

                    $('#makeForm').append("<label>"+insCleaned+"</label><input type='text' name='"+insCleaned+"' /><br>");
                });

$('#showCode').text("<form method='post' action='ADD PATH' id='" + myForm +"'>" + allCont +"<input type='submit' value='Submit' id='" + myForm +"Submit' /><form>");
```

the output comes as one long line, I would like a way to format it and include line breaks.

Comment: You mean you want your code to show pretty in the actual formed HTML? Can't you use `<br>`? Also, if this is for readability you could push your code to the next line and it wouldn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Yes it's mainly for readability. I allow the user to name fields and then the code is output so they can copy and paste the form into a web page. The output is all on one line though.

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760328/clearest-way-to-build-html-elements-in-jquery) as it might help you achieve your goal here.

Comment: Thanks, having a look now

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm trying to add data to a variable and want to include a line break after each addition.     eg: allCont += "<label>"+insCleaned+"</label>";    I then output the variable to a div with $('#showCode').text

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it formatted clearly because you want to check once the code, I would use the features of the code editors to reformat it just once to check it; for example, the free editor PsPad has a "reformat HTML" command which reorders the code in a clear manner.

If on the other side you want to view in the page the generated code as viewed through an editor, remember you should escape all < to &lt; and > to &gt; , and surround this in PRE tags.

Comment: Thanks, I previously tried escaping \n and using <pre> and nothing happens

Comment: Escaping and using <pre> guarantees that the whitespace you put in between the <pre> and </pre> tags will not be changed by the browser, but your Javascript code should produce correctly formatted code, if you want it to be that way.

In other terms, without PRE the browser does what it wants with indentation and spacing, with PRE it leaves indentation and spacing as it is, but it's your code that should produce correctly indented and spaced code...

Comment: Got this last week, hope this helps someone else. . . . I used quotes and then the concatenate symbol at the end. works a treat. Here is a snippet                                                           "let emptyCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('emptyCheck');" +
    "let i;" +
    "let empFlag = true;" +
    "let empAttr = \"\";" +
    "let datType = \"\";" +


      "for (i = 0; i < emptyCheck.length; i++) { " +

     "empAttr = \"err\" + emptyCheck[i].getAttribute('id'); " +
     "datType = empAttr.substr(3,3); " +
     "let errMessage = '';" +